# Python using Selenium to click on a button based on type, value, and class

Tags: python, selenium

So this is what the html looks like:

```
<button type="submit" name="page" value="2" class="_btn _btng">Next →</button>

<button type="submit" name="page" value="1" class="_btn">← Back</button>
```

And this is what I'm attempting:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Next')]").click()
```

For whatever reasons, this isn't actually clicking the button, it's just moving down to where the button is located and it just waits there. So maybe there's another hidden button somewhere that I can't visibly see that the code is "clicking" on. Not sure, so I guess my question really comes down to, is there a way where I can search for a button based on its value, type, and class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the `text` based search a shot. That's my favourite

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[.='Next →')]").click()
```

With `.` we are directly pointing to parent in `html` hierarchy and `*` allows you to do a search without depending on any specific `tag`

Comment: I tried doing that, but the → character doesn't seem to be understood... :(

Comment: In that case go for `//button[contains(text(), 'Next')]`

Comment: Have you tried `cssSelector` `[value='2'][class='_btn _btng']`

Comment: I have not tried using cssSelector, in the past it never seemed to work for me, but I'll give it a spin.

Comment: Actually! Using //button[... worked! Hmm, could you explain why //* did't work but //button did?

Comment: As I said with `*` you are doing a `tag` independent search. You might have some other tag say for example `a` with same text that's why it was failing. Now with `//button[....]` you are just searching button `tags` eliminating others.

Comment: Button contains worked for me for unsplash.com to load more content button. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

```
buttons = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//title[contains(text(),'Next')]")
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
time.sleep(2)
actions.click(button)
actions.perform()
```

Documentation on Selenium Action Chain here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains

Comment: Could you explain exactly what that's doing?

Comment: find the button with "next" text , create an action chain, press the button. There is even a delay by using the time sleep in case there is code loaded by ajax