# Selenium webdriver get text of adjacent column in same row by matching text from other column

Tags: java, c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing integration tests for an asp.net mvc website using Selenium Webdriver. I am using C# but answers in C# or Java would be appreciated. 
I have attached the html table and the generated html code.

*I want to **click** the **edit link** of groupname "**bcde**" using webdriver. To click the link, I **need the id (2138) & not group name (bcde).***
I have tried

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[contains(td[2], 'bcde')]/td[1]").ToList()[0])
```

but it gives 2137, id of abcde (alphabetically first group containing find string "bcde").
I need the id 2138 of the exact matching groupname "**bcde**".

[image]

```
<table class="table">
           <tr>
            <th>
                Group id
            </th>
            <th>
                Group Name
            </th>
            <th>

            </th>
    </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                2137
            </td>
            <td>
                abcde
            </td>
            <td>
                        <span><a href="/Group/Edit/2137" id="lnkGroupEdit">Edit</a> | </span>
                        <span> <a href="/Instrument?groupID=2137" id="lnkGroupDelete">Delete</a> | </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                2138
            </td>
            <td>
                bcde
            </td>
            <td>
                        <span><a href="/Group/Edit/2138" id="lnkGroupEdit">Edit</a> | </span>
                        <span> <a href="/Delete?groupID=2138" id="lnkGroupDelete">Delete</a> | </span>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                2139
            </td>
            <td>
                a bcde f
            </td>
            <td>
                        <span><a href="/Group/Edit/2139" id="lnkGroupEdit">Edit</a> | </span>
                        <span> <a href="/Instrument?groupID=2139" id="lnkGroupDelete">Delete</a> | </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Since u r using findElements to get a list...why don't u try with ToList()[1] for the group id. Unless until ur elements are dynamic. Also can u try out with text()='bcde' or starts-with(.,'bcde')?

Comment: @VivekSingh I couldn't make either work. Can you answer the question with complete xpath expressions with text & starts-with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below fixed it for me.

```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href=\"/Group/Edit/" + driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[contains(td[2], 'bcde')]/td[2]")).Where(t => t.Text.Equals(groupName)).ToList()[0].FindElement(By.XPath("..")).FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[1]")).Text + "\"]")).Click();
```

`.FindElement(By.XPath(".."))`  finds the parent element.

`**.//**` searches for all child elements.
So, `FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[1]"))`gives the first child of type **td**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
//tr/td[contains(.,'2137')]/..//span/a[.='Edit']
```

Notice the `.` See my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707930/python-using-selenium-to-click-on-a-button-based-on-type-value-and-class/27708070#27708070). `..` in `xpath` allows you to go back and forth of the `html` hierarchy easily. I used `contains` because the value of the `td` has `whitespaces`

**Edit**
Try this. Seems like it's a wait issue

```
By byXpath = By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(.,'2137')]/..//span/a[.='Edit']");
new WebDriverWait(Driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byXpath)).Click();
```

**2nd Edit**
Most interestingly the `a` tag that you are trying to click contains respective `id`. So the best solution of this problem is to use the following `xpath` as per my understanding

```
//a[contains(@href,'2138')][.='Edit']
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Edited your answer to add stacktrace, since it was too long   Feel free to edit again or rollback the edit.

Comment: Its not a wait issue.

Comment: I got Syntax Error: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: I am not convinced. can you put a break point and step in to make sure it's not wait issue. And, how many tables you got on that page?

Comment: try this as well `//tr/td[contains(text(),'2138')]/..//a[contains(@href,'Edit')]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67947/discussion-between-saifur-and-user2330678).

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393840/locating-the-node-by-value-containing-whitespaces-using-xpath) gives us some help.

Finding the exact text match is a little fiddly due to the whitespace surrounding what we see as the text. The XPath function `normalize-space()` cleans up the whitespace in the element text.

To locate the group name table cell containing exactly **"bcde"**, use the xPath string

```
//td[normalize-space() = 'bcde']
```

For the Group Id in the cell associated with that group name cell look at the immediately preceding cell with XPath string

```
//td[normalize-space() = 'bcde']/preceding-sibling::td
```

For the edit link we can find it in the following cell with this XPath string

```
//td[normalize-space() = 'bcde']/following-sibling::td//a[contains(.,'Edit')]
```