# Selenium search a text in td and get another td of same row

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My table looks like below:
**clm1  clm2  clm3**

1. 1  b  hi
2. 2  c  hello
3. 3  d  hi

Now the requirement is I have to find all the 'hi' and click on the other cell of same row. For e.g. in 1st occurance I have to click on 1 and the again on 3.

I am able to find 'hi' with below code but how to find the corresponding cell on the same row.

> List rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[text()='hi']"));

```
<table>
  <tr class="abc">
    <td class="efg">
      <a id="asg">1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="abc">
    <td class="efg">
      <span>1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="abc">
    <td class="efg">
      <span>1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please ignore the typo as I am typing from mobile.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the link to the site or even post the html code. Currently it is hard to  imagine how it actually looks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium webdriver get text of adjacent column in same row by matching text from other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710460/selenium-webdriver-get-text-of-adjacent-column-in-same-row-by-matching-text-from)

Comment: Can you rephrase the verbatim of the Question as per the HTML DOM you provided? I can see only one alphabet `1`. Still not sure how you find `hi` and `hello` both. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something simple in C#. I hope that you will be able to convert it to java.

```
var tableRows = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
foreach(var tableRow in tableRows)
{
   var td = tableRow.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
   if(td[2].Text.Contains("hi"))
   {
      td[0].FindElement(By.TagName("a")).Click();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`By.xpath("//td[./span[text()='hi']]/../td[1]")` would return the first column of that matching row.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you should use xpath:

**.//yourow/span[not(text()='Hi')][..//span[text()='Hi']]**

You get all "brothers" or "sisters" in html tree which do not have text Hi but are in the same row as cell contain text "Hi"